# Websocket blocks when downloading file via http to the same host

Tags: java, websocket, java-8, playframework-2.2, tyrus

I have a server running Java Play Framework 2.2.1 and a client application that connects via websockets to the server for monitoring and download files via http. I have the issue when downloading large files that the websockets messages block until the download ends on the client side of the connection. The client side is don with Java JDK8 and Tyrus library for websockets.

Does anybody know if there is any kind of priority between HTTP and Websockets (as far as I know Websockets are implemented over HTTP packages)?

Answer (score 1):

Once the initial bootsrapping is done by initiating an HTTP connection between client and server by requesting the upgrade to [Websocket protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), there is no more HTTP between the client and server.

WebSocket is the transport layer on TCP. Different from HTTP, it allows full-duplex communications over TCP connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, HTTP and Websockets are on the same level of priority when dispatching packages? Because this only implies that the connection is stablished by HTTP but after this all the handshaking is done by common TCP Sockets?

Comment: Yes the initial connection is HTTP. The Websocket handshaking is referred as this initial process that the server validates the upgrade. After that its Websocket over TCP. https://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html

Comment: OK. Thanks for the explanation about Web sockets, but I cannot understand why the websockets is being block until the download of the file is achieved. Then all the bytes enqueued are sent and received whithout any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the handler of the Tyrus library blocked any other operation with the Websocket. So we just start a new java thread inside the reception handler and leave this as quick as possible this thread.

Thanks for the suggestions before.